# PhpStorm: Can I sort properties/methods alphabetically?

Tags: phpstorm

Can I sort class properties and methods alphabetically.

I found that: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9883-intellij-idea-properties-sorter

Is there any similar for PhpStorm?

Comment: Yes -- "Rearrange code" is supported for PHP. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#arrange_code and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-code-style-php.html#27229f74

Answer (score 2):

First, to provide an answer to the question: [Arrange your code automatically with PhpStorm (re)arranger](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/arrange-your-code-automatically-with-phpstorm-rearranger/).

> To create a new rule, click the Add rule button in the upper right corner of the rules list. Configure it by type and modifier, add a name rule (like “init.*” or “*Test”) and/or set order type, if needed.

[image]

---

Now, in case someone is looking to sort selected text alphabetically, like I was trying to do, this might be able to help you: [String Manipulation](https://github.com/krasa/StringManipulation).

I wanted to select some text (like class imports in TypeScript) and order it alphabetically. I tried with the built-in code rearranger, but found it didn't work for just this simple purpose.

Source: [How to sort text lines?](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206600895-How-to-sort-text-lines-)

Comment: Please include here the code and information presents in the linked pages, they may not be online in the future.

Comment: The links provided are for a PhpStorm tutorial, plugin and support forum question. I don't think copying whole articles here is the right way of doing things, instead of providing links to them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, **Provide context for links** Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. *Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline*.

Comment: Is this better?